# What statistical tests should be applied to the attached distributions?

Tags: distributions, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In the attached images (bottom of this post), I wish to compare the plotted distributions as follows. Each plot shows two distributions labelled 'Forwards' and 'Backwards'. For each attached example, I wish to compare each of 'Forwards' and 'Backwards' of sub-figure a with 'Forwards' and 'Backwards' of sub-figure c (and same for sub-figures b and d)

Now considering a and c from the distros A example, the distributions are approximately bimodal. I was thinking of taking the absolute values of these distributions so that they are no longer bimodal and then comparing them. (Probably I'm barking up the wrong tree with this?)

However, I am uncertain as to what test I should use to test for differences. I was initially inclining towards a ranksum test since the distributions are clearly non-uniform. But, I was also maybe considering a Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test.

EDIT: Note about distributions: Each 'Forwards' and 'Backwards' data distribution consists of ~7000 and ~5000 data points respectively. Each data point within a given data set indicates the difference in value of a property specific to an artificial neural network. Hence all data points represent such measurements over collections (~7000 and ~5000) of neural networks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain where these distributions came from? For example, what sort of data is it and what were the sample sizes?

Comment: Edit added above

Comment: My approach would be not to do any tests, and instead to just describe what I see. Others may disagree. I would consider the question "how much of a difference is there (if any)?" rather than "is there a difference?".

Comment: I agree with @mark999. It's clear that there is a difference - you don't need a statistical test to see that. What are your scientific goals? To see if there is a difference, to describe the difference or something else?

Comment: Thanks both. I guess I wish to see how significant the differences are. For example, highly significant differences are suggested to exist between (a) and (c) of the distros 2 example (if I ran the tests correctly that is), but visually, the distributions look the same...

Comment: Speaking generally (not specifically about your data), if the sample size is very large, tiny differences (which are not of any practical significance) can be highly statistically significant.

Comment: one more point to consider: having a bimodal distribution may indicate that there are two types of observational objects mixed together. If you can find out which the underlying criterion is you can account for it in an ANOVA-style analysis and have to compare distributions that are unimodal - and (regarding the sample sizes) with means hopefully normally distributed.

Comment: mark999 -- that almost seems counter-intuitive to me. I thought that it was when the sample size is small that tiny differences become more apparent (since in larger distributions, a greater number of points bleed out small differences thus making them negligible). Nevertheless, based on your comment, would it make sense to sample from the distributions to produce smaller distributions and then compare those instead? @psj -- I am unfamiliar with the ANOVA test but will look into it. Cheers.

Comment: @ben-j NOOO! It means that you should not fixate on statistical significance. Try to find an estimate of the extent of the difference in meaningful units.

Comment: I get your point Ben: in example 2, distributions (a) and (c) do look similar, so there is a genuine issue here concerning whether they should be considered different.  But the apparent similarity arises because the histograms used to show the distributions are poor tools for making distinctions among distributions.  Have you looked at [Q-Q plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Q_plot) to compare them?

Comment: @Ben, I don't understand your intuition. Suppose you had two normal distributions, one having a (population) mean of 0 and the other having a mean of 0.01, and each having a variance of 1. If you took a sample of 20 from each distribution, do you think that would be enough to convince you that the two distributions are different? Probably not, because the difference in population means is so small. What if the sample sizes were 20000 instead of 20? Then there would be more chance that the difference could be seen - the estimates of the means and their difference (continued)

Comment: are more precise (have lower standard error). As the sample size increases, the statistical power of the test increases. However, the difference of 0.01 may be too small to be of any practical significance, depending on what the distributions represent. I agree with Aniko - it wouldn't make sense to sample from your data and test those smaller samples.